# Android: how to restore the SMS backup XML I created

Tags: android, xml, sms

I have an application that creates an XML file as shown bellow. I need to restore it back to the phone messages. Please advice me on how to do it.

Details printing of the SMS

```
id
thread_id
address
person
date
data_sent
protocol
read
status
type
reply_path_present
subject
body
service_center
locked
error_code
seen
```

XML output

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<Document>
   <SMS_Details>625,67,+9477xxxxxx,1610,1402985905350,1402985900000,0,1,-1,1,0,null,aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa,+9477xxxxxx,0,0,null</SMS_Details>


</Document>
```

Comment: Get the text in the sms and then split will be ok.

Comment: i need to restore the SMS that i backed up. thats what i want to know, how to do it

Comment: I think you need do some research on its database,the file /data/data/com.android.providers.telephony/databases/mmssms.db